# score system in pygame gives this error TypeError: text must be a unicode or bytes

Tags: pygame

Im having some trouble understanding why the following code gives a typerror: text must be a unicode or bytes;

```
def draw_text(self, text, size, color, x, y):
    font = pg.font.Font(self.font_name, size)
    text_surface = font.render(text, True, color)  - error is in this line
    text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
    text_rect.midtop = (x, y)
    self.screen.blit(text_surface, text_rect)
```

Comment: Have you tried `text = str(text)`? and what exactly are you trying to display that's raising all the errors?

Comment: ah yes that seems to work now! thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

Try `text = str(text)`. Pygame usually requires a string, and based on the error you're giving it something that's not a string